# How to double click android back button with Appium?

Tags: java, appium, ui-automation

I am trying to write automation UI tests with Appium. I have this problem: I can't make a method that automatically clicks twice on the *back* button of an Android device.

When I use `driver.navigate().back()`, the automation clicks only once on the back button. Even if I write this line twice, the double click is not performed.

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to press KeyEvents in Appium, through pressKey();. You could try using this method twice in a row (maybe with a sleep in between to allow the engine some space/reaction time. Because what means double click for you?) as following:

```
driver.pressKey(new KeyEvent(AndroidKey.BACK));
Thread.sleep(200);
driver.pressKey(new KeyEvent(AndroidKey.BACK));
```

Hope this will solve your issue.

Comment: it doesn't work because I use AppiumDriver driver and not AndroidDriver

Comment: @justpetro try it with a Thread.sleep(300); in between driver.navigate().back(); when executing it twice.

Comment: I switched all my AppiumDrivers with AndroidDrivers and the code you've given me worked, thank you very much!

Comment: Great work man!